# What are Tor Node Selection Rules?

Tags: exit-relays, source-code, guard-node, implementations, middle

What are the rules by which Tor Proxies select entry, exit, and middle nodes from the list of Tor nodes? Where is this implemented in the source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules for selecting nodes can be found in the [path-spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/path-spec.txt). Specifically in [§2.2 Path selection and constraints](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/path-spec.txt?id=426e9ac1069ee843000aaeed9260ba4c9733af00#n184).

A few points from the section:

> - We do not choose the same router twice for the same path.
> - We do not choose any router in the same family as another in the same
>     path. (Two routers are in the same family if each one lists the other
>     in the "family" entries of its descriptor.)
> - We do not choose more than one router in a given /16 subnet
>     (unless EnforceDistinctSubnets is 0).
> - We don't choose any non-running or non-valid router unless we have
>     been configured to do so. By default, we are configured to allow
>     non-valid routers in "middle" and "rendezvous" positions.
> - If we're using Guard nodes, the first node must be a Guard (see 5
>     below)
>
>   For "fast" circuits, we only choose nodes with the Fast flag. For
>     non-"fast" circuits, all nodes are eligible.
>
>   For all circuits, we weight node selection according to router
>     bandwidth.
>
>   We also weight the bandwidth of Exit and Guard flagged nodes
>     depending on    the fraction of total bandwidth that they make up and
>     depending upon the    position they are being selected for.

...

> Additionally, we may be building circuits with one or more requests
>   in    mind.  Each kind of request puts certain constraints on paths:
>
> - All service-side introduction circuits and all rendezvous paths
>     should be Stable.
> - All connection requests for connections that we think will need to
>        stay open a long time require Stable circuits.  Currently, Tor decides
>        this by examining the request's target port, and comparing it to a
>        list of "long-lived" ports. (Default: 21, 22, 706, 1863, 5050,
>        5190, 5222, 5223, 6667, 6697, 8300.)
> - DNS resolves require an exit node whose exit policy is not equivalent
>        to "reject *:*".
> - Reverse DNS resolves require a version of Tor with advertised eventdns
>        support (available in Tor 0.1.2.1-alpha-dev and later).
> - All connection requests require an exit node whose exit policy
>        supports their target address and port (if known), or which "might
>        support it" (if the address isn't known).  See 2.2.1.
>
> **2.2.1. Choosing an exit**
>
> If we know what IP address we want to connect to or resolve, we can
>   trivially tell whether a given router will support it by simulating
>   its declared exit policy.
>
> Because we often connect to addresses of the form hostname:port, we
>   do not    always know the target IP address when we select an exit
>   node.  In these    cases, we need to pick an exit node that "might
>   support" connections to a    given address port with an unknown
>   address.  An exit node "might support"    such a connection if any
>   clause that accepts any connections to that port    precedes all
>   clauses (if any) that reject all connections to that port.
>
> Unless requested to do so by the user, we never choose an exit node
>   flagged as "BadExit" by more than half of the authorities who
>   advertise    themselves as listing bad exits.

Comment: Thanks! Should questions about actual implementation be apart of another question? What are guard nodes?

Comment: No, I think the implementation being here is fine, I just wasn't sure off the top of my head. Guard nodes are entry nodes (the first node in a Tor circuit).