# Are relays chosen by location proximity, e.g. county, for circuit building?

Tags: relays, onion-routing, circuit

Are relays chosen by location proximity, e.g. county, for circuit building?

I know that there [exists some rules](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/1659/28661) but I didn't read anything about location. If the location of a client is not considered, does this mean that almost all the traffic from, e.g., Asian clients gets routed through Europe?

There is a lack of relays in Asia due to bandwidth limitations of hosting providers. But I would assume, that it would make sense to localize the circuit building to keep circuit round-trip latencies low. If the relay selection is mainly done based on available bandwidth, relays from Europe will always be preferred (and thus provide high latencies for Asian clients).

Answer (score 0):

Relay locations are are not chosen by location, but you do have the [option](https://support.torproject.org/tbb/tbb-16/) of limiting locations where you can get exit nodes though this will also limit your anonymity.